# what causes to be only 1 concurrent connection?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, nginx

I have a PHP web app.
When multiple simultaneous AJAX requests occur, it seems they are queued on the server side like only one process is run at one time. It only happens when all the requests are done from one browser.

The weirdest thing is that sometimes it runs as it should, simultaneously (screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRk9C.jpg ) and after like 10 minutes it waits one process to be done and only then it runs another process doing them one-by-one (screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO6N8.jpg ).

The code for test screenshots:

```php
sleep(5);
exit();
```

P.S. when these AJAX requests are queued, also normal html requests are 'waiting in the queue'.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is highly likely that this has something to do with session management.

What happens is that a new request waits for the session in the previous request to be closed.

> This only happens because session data is accessed, and thus a lock is obtained on the session file.

You can avoid this by not starting the session in the first place. If you need the session you need to close the session right after it was started. If you need to set $_SESSION variables you need this before closing the session. You can do this like so:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['some'] = 'value';
session_write_close(); // From here on out, concurrent requests are no longer blocked
```

$_SESSION variables will still be available after closing the session.

See also: https://codingexplained.com/coding/php/solving-concurrent-request-blocking-in-php

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was expecting somebody would point to session_write_close and also `'output_buffering' = 0` in php.ini
But the thing is that sometimes it works with the very same requests and it doesnt queue.
The behaviour is really strange.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried to change the code to close the session though? If no, you should try that first, just to be sure. And otherwise: can you maybe post a little more code that could be relevant to the problem?

Comment: after hours of tests using `session_write_close();` has decreased the time slightly, but sometimes these requests still stack up in queue.
The behaviour is very similar to what it's been before
Thank for your help but I guess the answer to my case lies somewhere really near